# Updating HTML text and an image from an AJAX Call server response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to update my front end HTML with javascript from an AJAX call to a php page. My php page, ajax_check_instagram.php returns a 0 or a 1 if the account name data sent to it exists or not. I want to then update my front end as the user types.

I think everything is correct?

```js
$(document).ready(function() { //When the dom is ready 
  $("#instagram").change(function() { //if theres a change in the username textbox
    var acc = $("#instagram").val(); //Get the value in the username textbox
    if (acc.length > 3) { //if the lenght greater than 3 characters
      $("#availability_status").html('<img src="/img/ajax-loader.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;Checking availability...');
      //Add a loading image in the span id="availability_status"

      $.ajax({ //Make the Ajax Request
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax_check_instagram.php", //file name
        data: "instagram=" + acc, //data
        success: function(server_response) {
          $("#availability_status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request) {
            if (server_response == '0') { //if ajax_check_username.php return value "0"
              $("#availability_status").html('<img src="/img/icon-success.png" align="absmiddle" style="height: 15px; width: auto; margin-top: -2px;"> <font color="#c9dc54" style="padding-top: 5px;"> Confirmed! </font>  ');
              //add this image to the span with id "availability_status"
            } else if (server_response == '1') { //if it returns "1"
              $("#availability_status").html('<img src="/img/icon-error.png" align="absmiddle" style="height: 15px; width: auto; margin-top: -2px;"> <font color="#b11116" style="padding-top: 5px;">Not Valid. </font>');
            }
          });
        }
      });
    } else {
      $("#availability_status").html('<font color="#b11116">Instagram Account Not Found</font>');
      //if in case the username is less than or equal 3 characters only 
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<span id="availability_status" class="pull-right" style="padding-right: 5px;">Status</span>
<input id="instagram" name="instagram">
```

Also here is a JSFiddle link!

http://jsfiddle.net/3taudxef/

Comment: why are you adding ajaxComplete inside success function, thats not needed

Comment: You didn't include jQuery?: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: It is included in a page which has jquery referenced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ajaxComplete` is used to register handler that is called when Ajax request completes, you already have `success` function of [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), so thats not needed,remove `ajaxComplete` function, change your code to:

```
 ...
    success: function(server_response){
       if(server_response == '0') { 
            $("#availability_status").html('<img src="/img/icon-success.png" align="absmiddle" style="height: 15px; width: auto; margin-top: -2px;"> <font color="#c9dc54" style="padding-top: 5px;"> Confirmed! </font>  ');
        }  
        else if(server_response == '1') {  
            $("#availability_status").html('<img src="/img/icon-error.png" align="absmiddle" style="height: 15px; width: auto; margin-top: -2px;"> <font color="#b11116" style="padding-top: 5px;">Not Valid. </font>');   
        }    
    });

...
```

**Update**::if you want to ajax call on every key press after length of 3, then use `keyup` event instead of `change` event, as:

```
...
$("#instagram").keyup(function() {
...
```

Comment: I tried updating the success function with it but it did not work.

Comment: @SlowPoke see my update, and check in browser console to see if ajax request is being made..

Comment: I do not see any errors, this is the JSFiddle link.
http://jsfiddle.net/3taudxef/6/

Comment: @SlowPoke seems you have some js errors in your fiddle code, see this updated code:: http://jsfiddle.net/3taudxef/7/ , though it wont work completely as there's ajax request made to non-existent page..!